# How to test JPA in Arquillian

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to use Arquillian to test my JPA repository classes. However I only get nullpointer exception telling me that it doesn't find the persistence.xml. How do you configure it in a standard Maven project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked @ the official documentation [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/). The [project structure](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/#project_structure) suggests that its built using Maven.

If you still run into issues do post the exception messages.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ShrinkWrap deployment does not contain the persistence.xml in the right path. The persistence.xml file should be located in the META-INF directory of a JAR, or in WEB-INF/META-INF directory of a WAR. You could verify this in two ways:

1. Through the verbosity flag of the `Archive.toString(...)` method:

   In your `@Deployment` method, you can print out the contents of the archive, using the `toString` method, like

   ```
   @Deployment
   public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
          WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addClasses(Foo.class);
          System.out.println(war.toString(true));
          return war;
   }
   ```
2. Configuring Arquillian to write the generated deployment to disk:

   You can add the `engine` configuration element to your arquillian.xml with the `deploymentdeploymentExportPath` property, like

   ```
   <engine>
       <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/deployment</property>
   </engine>
   ```

   This would instruct Arquillian to write the deployments it generates into a subdirectory under the target directory generated by Maven.

Answer (score 0):

There is also bunch of examples in the [showcase project on github](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-showcase), including JPA testing (also using Arquillian Persistence Extension).

Hopefully this will lead to you to the right path :)